# Regex - Optimize look behind

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that finds urls in a source code

```
(?<!\b(XmlNamespace)\([^\n]{0,1000})"(http|ftp|socket):\/\/(?!www\.google-analytics\.com(\/collect)?)(\:(\d+)?)?("|\/))[\w\d]
```

But it VERY slow. The main problem is look behind.
I use Java (java.util.regex.Pattern)
Can someone help me please?

UPD:

When I changed {0,1000} to {0,100}, processing time has changed to 50 seconds. But it's not a solution. I believe that this look behind works first, but the main part only second. So the question: How to make "(http|ftp|socket):// work first and look behind only after that?

Comment: How are you using this regex?.. Are you compiling it only once or are you compiling it each time your method is called?

Comment: Only once, of course. Just I use it for processing ~5k files and only this regex works ~600 seconds, but other without look behind work no more than 1 second.

Comment: Well. It doesn't work that way. Look behind is considered first and when it matches, whatever follows will be considered.

Comment: I already understood that, but how it might be optimized to work fast and have the same functionality in my case?

Comment: Try `"(http|ftp|socket)://(?<!\bXmlNamespace\(.{0,1000}"(http|ftp|socket)://)(?!www\.google-analytics\.com(/collect)?)(:\d*)?["/]\w`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The regex was [tested at RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/4zhfya).**

**NOTE**: The `(?!www\\.google-analytics\\.com(/collect)?)` lookahead does not make much sense since you are consuming `:` + digits* after `//`, so your regex **might be invalid in general**.

***I dwell on how the pattern can be enhanced***.

The point is that the lookbehind in your pattern is triggered at alocation before every character. If you place it after the initial pattern *repeating this pattern after the subpattern that is already in your lookbehind*, it will be triggered only after matching this initial subpattern.

Fortunately, Java regex is wise enough to see that the lookbehind width is still constrained width with the alternation.

So,

```
"(http|ftp|socket)://(?<!\bXmlNamespace\(.{0,1000}"(http|ftp|socket)://)(?!www\‌​.google-analytics\.com(/collect)?)(:\d*)?["/]\w
```

Should work better. Note I removed unnecessary escape symbols (`/` is not a special character in Java regex), put the `("|/)` alternation into a character class `[...]`. Also, `[\w\d]` is the same as `\w` (it already matches `\d`).

**The regex was [tested at RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/4zhfya).**

[Java test](http://ideone.com/4BMbMN):

```
String value1 = "\"http://:2123\"123";
String pattern1 = "\"(http|ftp|socket)://(?<!\\bXmlNamespace\\(.{0,1000}\"(http|ftp|socket)://)(?!www\\.google-analytics\\.com(/collect)?)(:\\d*)?[\"/]\\w";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(value1);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println("true");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```